# Fuji bolt fell out please help!

Tags: crankset, parts, cottered-cranks

[image]Hi all. I have an old Fuji and there's a bolt that holds the crank in place. It fell out and is lost unfortunately and I am looking for a new one. Does anyone have any ideas? I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 11):

The crank appears to be a cottered crank and hence the missing part is a cotter pin. See the article by Sheldon Brown about cottered cranks https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cotters.html

These parts can be bought but because this kind of attachment is quite old-style, not every shop may have them. You need to know the right diameter. The common ones are 9 mm or (more common) 9.5 mm (3/8 inch).

However, the cotters are usually hard to get out. Perhaps you may be just missing the nut on it? The photo is very blurry and it is not clear to me whether it shows the current state or the state before it fell out.